# Solr suggestions with weight field - Analyzinginfixsuggester

Tags: solr, lucene

I am using SOLR to generate suggestions. I have given a float field named length  (tfloat) as the weightField in solrconfig.xml. But in my suggestions, this value does not come up in the suggestion response and shows as zero. I was expecting the suggestions to be sorted by weight and the weight to hold the value of length which represents the string length of the suggestions. I am using solr 6.2.1

```xml
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent"> 
    <lst name="suggester"> 
        <str name="name">mySuggester</str> 
        <str name="lookupImpl">AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory</str> 
        <str name="indexPath">suggester_infix_dir</str>
        <str name="payloadField">payload</str> 
        <str name="weightField">lengthval</str>--> 
        <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str> 
        <str name="field">value</str> 
        <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text_general</str> 
        <str name="buildOnStartup">true</str> 
        <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str> 
        <str name="highlight">false</str>
```

---

```xml
<requestHandler name="/suggesthandler" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy"> 
    <lst name="defaults"> 
        <str name="suggest">true</str> 
        <str name="suggest.count">900</str> 
        <str name="suggest.dictionary">mySuggester</str> 
    </lst> 
    <arr name="components"> 
        <str>suggest</str> 
    </arr> 
</requestHandler>
```

Comment: Please share the config that you are using for suggester.

Comment: <str name="payloadField">payload</str> 
<str name="weightField">lengthval</str>-->
    <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
    <str name="field">value</str>
    <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text_general</str>
    <str name="buildOnStartup">true</str>
    <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
 <str name="highlight">false</str>

Comment: <searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
   <lst name="suggester">
    <str name="name">mySuggester</str>
 
 
 <str name="lookupImpl">AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory</str>
    <str name="indexPath">suggester_infix_dir</str>

Comment: <requestHandler name="/suggesthandler" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
   <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="suggest">true</str>
    <str name="suggest.count">900</str>
    <str name="suggest.dictionary">mySuggester</str>
   </lst>
    <arr name="components">
     <str>suggest</str>
    </arr>
   </requestHandler>

Comment: @redeemed - I've added this to your question. When you need to provide additional code, you can edit your question and add it there, instead of posting it in comments. Much easier to read.

Comment: Thank you , i'll take care of this henceforth . Sorry for doing so .

Comment: Hello , Any updates on the answer ?

Comment: Hello it started working , not sure what was wrong

Answer (score 0):

Hello it started working , not sure what was wrong